# WebPack loading none existing budle.js files

Tags: reactjs, webpack

When building my react application i get a error that webpack/bootstrap is trying to access {n}.budle.js files that dosn't exist in my dist folder. I only get this error when uploading to a server locally the code is not trying to access these files in dist folder.

Error

[image]

Files in dist, no budle files

[image]

Webpack.prod.js

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    entry: {
        index: "./src/index.tsx"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
    },

    devtool: "source-map",
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: "Template",
            template: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html')
        }),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({ log: (t) => console.log(t) }),       
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/,
                use: "url-loader?limit=100000"
            },
            { test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)?/, include: [path.join(__dirname, 'src')], use: { loader: 'babel-loader' } },
            { test: /\.css$/i, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'], },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        enforceExtension: false,
        extensions: [".jsx", ".js", ".tsx", ".ts", ".json", ".png"],
        alias: {
            "~": path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
        },
    }
}
```

The entry point to the site is site.com/something/index.html is that a issue?

Comment: Did you try defining `output.publicPath` configuration? [docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/#root)

Comment: @RazRonen yes i tried that, but i got it to work when using http: and not https: dont know why it would differ

Comment: Interesting, thanks for updating.